# GPS cannot lock location while mobile data is on

Tags: android, gps, gsm

GPS always cannot detect or lock on my location, it happened intermittently. After awhile, it able to detect again but not for long it will lost signal again. I've tried many diff apps and also set it to high accuracy but it still the same. Then I found out that when I off my mobile data, GPS able to lock on my location. I am using android kitkat version 4.4.4

Comment: mobile data has nothing to do with GPS AFAIK. Please post your code!

Comment: Some phones have very bad gps chips. Or those chips do not get enough power when mobile is on too. Buy another phone.

Comment: @greenapps, I tried put in other sim with different telco networks, it works fine with mobile data on.

Comment: Do you mean that it GPS works, then when you ddo a phone call its gets bad, and then after the phone call its gets good again?

Comment: I cannot imagine why another sim will solve the hardware problem. Maybe it was luck, because the satellite constelation was luckily better at that time.

Comment: @AlexWien, the GPS is working fine when set it to 'Device Only", just that when I turn on mobile data (3G), GPS signal will lost and can't lock on my location. Could it be the AGPS problem?

Comment: No, the GPS chip ignores the AGPS data, if they are invalid. in that case after 30-45s latest you should get a location. MAybe it#s just a cheap device, not having enough power  for both.

Answer (score 0):

If that happends with different Apps, as you told, then it is an hardware problem. Use another phone.